# SoftDelete in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

### Problem Statement

I have created a base model:

```
class CreateUpdateDeleteModel(models.Model):
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    from django.utils.text import gettext_lazy as _

    from .managers import BakeryManager

    from drfaddons.datatypes import UnixTimestampField

    create_date = UnixTimestampField(_('Create Date'), auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_creator')

    delete_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Delete Date'), null=True, blank=True)
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_destroyer')

    update_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date Modified'), auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_editor')

    objects = BakeryManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I want that in my system, all the elements are soft deleted i.e. whenever an object is deleted, it should behave as follow:

1. Behave like normal delete operation: Raise error if `models.PROTECT` is set as value for `on_delete`, set null if it's `models.SET_NULL` and so on.
2. Set `delete_date`
3. Never show it anywhere (incl. admin) in any query. Even `model.objects.all()` should not include deleted objects.

How do I do this?
I am thinking to override `get_queryset()` which may solve `problem 3`. But what about `1` & `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange request.

Point 1. It's not clear. Show an error where?

Point 2. The delete is managed as a status and not a hide of the data. I would suggest you add a status field and manage the delete using a special function that changes the status. You can override the `delete`, but be aware that the delete in queryset does not call the Model.delete but run directly SQL code.

Saying that it's a bad idea. The delete must be there, but just not used. You can easily remove the delete form the Django admin and a developer has no reason to delete code unless he/she is playing with the Django shell irresponsibly. (DB backup?)

Point 3. If you don't want to show the data in admin, simply override the Admin ModelForm to hide the data when the STATUS of the object is DELETE. It's bad design manipulate the domain to accommodate the presentation layer.

Comment: 1. Raise a code. Apologies. 
2. Understood. Any code in `views` will invoke `delete` from `foo.delete()` where `foo` is an object of class.
3. How do I override all the querysets to apply the filter: `.filter(delete_date=None)`?

I have updated the points as per your comment. Thanks

Comment: Point 2: I understand that the code in view can delete the object (and also in other parts of the app), but you should write tests to be sure that nothing is deleted.

Comment: Yup. Working on same. Any idea on how do I override all querysets?

Comment: I'm still on the opinion that you are following a very hard path, but you can override the object manager https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset

Comment: Yes indeed. You're right. Finally, I was able to convince client that this is something they do not want to have. I am going to close the question with your answer. I will add something to it:

In case we even override the `get_queryset()` in `Manager` class and set it as object manager, we will achieve the result, but the whole concept of soft delete posses another thread: Data redundancy. What if someone want to recreate that data? Thus, the whole Django system & DBMS structure is threaten.